# Bootstrap columns in loop with php

Tags: php, loops

I'm trying to show my news block with bootstrap4 as

[image]

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card mb-4">
      <a href="$arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]"><img src="$arItem["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["SRC"]"</a>
    </div>

    <div class="card mb-4">
          <a href="$arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]"><img src="$arItem["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["SRC"]"</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card mb-4">
        <a href="$arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]"><img src="$arItem["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["SRC"]"</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4">
         <a href="$arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]"><img src="$arItem["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["SRC"]"</a>
    </div>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="card mb-big">
        <a href="$arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]"><img src="$arItem["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["SRC"]"</a>
  </div>     
</div>
```

I have an array with results of database query in

```
$arResult["ITEMS"]
```

I want to do this with loop by

```
<? foreach ($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem): ?>   

 <?endforeach?>
```

I know i need to use something like

```
$i=0
  if (i===2){ 
   } else if ($k === 4) {
    } else {}
  $i++;
```

but how can i remove `col-md-3` from loop.

```
<?php
 $i=0
  foreach ($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem): ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="card mb-4"></div>
    </div>

  if (i===2){ 
    <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="card mb-4"></div>
    </div>
   } 
   if (i===4){ 
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="card mb-4"></div>
    </div>
   }
```

I'm afraid I'm a little confused. How to show it in one loop?

Comment: Do you have the exact count of values (eg: 5) in your array?

Comment: *"but how can i remove col-md-3 from loop ... `<code>`"* *"I know i need to use something like...`<code>`"* - That appears to be pseudo code. If that isn't, then you have parse errors and undefined constants. You should also show us a diagram of what you're getting now, just like the one you posted for what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have 5 elements in the array, you could use `%2` (modulo) to write `<div class="col-md-3">` and check if it's the last element to change `col-md-3` to `col-md-6` and `mb-4` to `mb-big`:

```
if (!empty($arResult["ITEMS"])) {

    foreach ($arResult["ITEMS"] as $k => $item) {

        $is_last = $k == count($arResult["ITEMS"]) - 1;

        if ($k%2 == 0) {
            echo '<div class="'.($is_last?'col-md-6':'col-md-3').'">';
        }

        echo'  <div class="card '.($is_last?'mb-big':'mb-4').'"></div>';

        if ($k%2 == 1) echo '</div>';
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Will output (reformatted):

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="card mb-4"></div>
  <div class="card mb-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="card mb-4"></div>
  <div class="card mb-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="card mb-big"></div>
</div>
```